He gets to feeling or feel

He gets to feel ashamed.


He gets to feeling ashamed.

Generally, we use base form of the verb after 'to' but I have read the second sentence in which the writer has used 'feeling' instead of 'feel' after the preposition 'to'. Are both sentences correct? Do they mean the same meaning or there is some difference?

I wouldn't use gets to at all in this context; we usually use it of pleasant things, like 'He gets to see his favourite singer'. I would say 'He starts to feel ashamed' (or begins to, grows to.)

@KateBunting - yes. 'I got to feeling' sounds a bit US rural.

This may be a big US/UK split.  As a USA native, I find that "I get to ___ing" sounds perfectly natural.
